# Bash script - Loop through directory with regex

Tags: linux, bash

I'm sure this must be possible, but I'm not sure how. What I'm trying to do is loop through a directory, looking for numeric directories within, and get their disk space. This is what I've come up with, but it's not dealing with the regex.

```
FILES="$DIR_PATH/secure/{[0-9]+}"
for f in $FILES
do
   used=`du -s $f`
   base=`basename $f`
   mysql --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASS --host=$DB_HOST $DB_NAME << EOF
       INSERT INTO disk_usage(site_id, filesystem, used, size) VALUES("$base", "Private Files", "$used", "$size")
EOF
done
```

In case it's not clear, I have a directory containing a bunch of directories with numeric names. This directory also contains some other files/directories that I don't want to calculate disk space on. So I just want to loop through the directory and get the disk space used by each numeric subdirectory. I'm sure this isn't optimal code, but it's being run privately on a safe filesystem, so the risk of problems is pretty low, but if there is a way to improve it, please let me know.

Comment: Be aware of https://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @glennjackman Not worried about SQL injection here since all of the data is forced to be numeric by the underlying utilities generating the data. Also, it's just a private system with no third party access, so not a problem. Best practice? No. But good enough for what I need right now :)

Comment: Not relevant to the root question, but prefer the `$(...)` instead of backticks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using bash's [extended patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching)

```sh
shopt -s extglob
for subdir in "$DIR_PATH"/secure/+([[:digit:]])/
# ...............................^^-----------^
...
```

Note the trailing slash: that limits the results to directories only, ignoring *files* named with all digits.

Comment: Thank you! I'm normally a Python/PHP developer, and just getting into bash for systems tasks. Lots to learn still, obviously :)

Comment: Use https://shellcheck.net to help with bash errors and best practices.